# Custom post type metabox array

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I am trying to create a custom post type with custom metabox array. How can I create this kind a automatic populating post type? I think I have to use two dimension array. But how can I automatically populate my data array? And how can I save this kind array.

Could some one point me to right direction?

**Please take a look at the images.**

[image: Img1]

Second img
[image]

My code so far :

```
<?php
//add custom field - price
add_action("admin_init", "price");

function object_init(){
  add_meta_box("price_meta", "Price fields :", "object", "price_meta", "normal", "low");

}


function price_meta(){
 global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $price = $custom["price"][0];
  ?>

  <p style="float:left;"><label>Nr :</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="priceNr" size="10" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"/>
</p>
  <p style="float:left;"><label>Description :</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="priceD" size="50" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"/>
</p>
  <p style="float:left;"><label>Price :</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="price" size="20" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"/>
</p>

  <?php
}
//Save product price
add_action('save_post', 'save_detailss');

function save_detailss(){ 
global $post; 

$post_id = $post->ID; 

// to prevent metadata or custom fields from disappearing... 
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
return $post_id; 

update_post_meta($post_id, "price", $_POST["price"]); 

}   

?>
```

Comment: Can you post your code that generates the metaboxes

Comment: I updated the code, but it is relay just a basics. I think $price I have to create a two dimension array. But I dont know from witch way I have to start. My PHP isnt that good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code make no sense, anyway here is a nice way to do it and you get:
[image]

```
function Print_price_fileds($cnt, $p = null) {
if ($p === null){
    $a = $b = $c = '';
}else{
    $a = $p['n'];
    $b = $p['d'];
    $c = $p['p'];
}
return  <<<HTML
<li>
    <label>Nr :</label>
    <input type="text" name="price_data[$cnt][n]" size="10" value="$a"/>

    <label>Description :</label>
    <input type="text" name="price_data[$cnt][d]" size="50" value="$b"/>

    <label>Price :</label>
    <input type="text" name="price_data[$cnt][p]" size="20" value="$c"/>
    <span class="remove">Remove</span>
</li>
HTML
;
}


//add custom field - price
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "object_init");

function object_init(){
  add_meta_box("price_meta_id", "Price fields :","price_meta", "post", "normal", "low");

}

function price_meta(){
 global $post;

  $data = get_post_meta($post->ID,"price_data",true);
  echo '<div>';
  echo '<ul id="price_items">';
  $c = 0;
    if (count($data) > 0){
        foreach((array)$data as $p ){
            if (isset($p['p']) || isset($p['d'])|| isset($p['n'])){
                echo Print_price_fileds($c,$p);
                $c = $c +1;
            }
        }

    }
    echo '</ul>';

    ?>
        <span id="here"></span>
        <span class="add"><?php echo __('Add Price Data'); ?></span>
        <script>
            var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
                $(document).ready(function() {
                var count = <?php echo $c - 1; ?>; // substract 1 from $c
                $(".add").click(function() {
                    count = count + 1;
                    //$('#price_items').append('<li><label>Nr :</label><input type="text" name="price_data[' + count + '][n]" size="10" value=""/><label>Description :</label><input type="text" name="price_data[' + count + '][d]" size="50" value=""/><label>Price :</label><input type="text" name="price_data[' + count + '][p]" size="20" value=""/><span class="remove">Remove</span></li>');
                   $('#price_items').append('<? echo implode('',explode("\n",Print_price_fileds('count'))); ?>'.replace(/count/g, count));
                    return false;
                });
                $(".remove").live('click', function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>#price_items {list-style: none;}</style>
    <?php
    echo '</div>';
}


//Save product price
add_action('save_post', 'save_detailss');

function save_detailss($post_id){ 
global $post;


    // to prevent metadata or custom fields from disappearing... 
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return $post_id; 
    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    if (isset($_POST['price_data'])){
        $data = $_POST['price_data'];
        update_post_meta($post_id,'price_data',$data);
    }else{
        delete_post_meta($post_id,'price_data');
    }
}
```

I keep getting people asking me how to get the data to print in the fronend so:

```
$data = get_post_meta($post->ID,"price_data",true);
echo '<ul>';
    if (count($data) > 0){
        foreach((array)$data as $p ){
            if (isset($p['p']) || isset($p['d'])|| isset($p['n'])){
                echo '<li>Number: '.$p['n'].' Description: '.$p['d'].' Price: '.$p['p'].'</li>';
            }
        }
    }
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Nice job! 
Need a little help getting this working on attachment page. I changed:

`add_meta_box("price_meta_id", "Price fields :","price_meta", "post", "normal", "low");`

to:

`add_meta_box("price_meta_id", "Price fields :","price_meta", "attachment", "normal", "low");`

It appeared  on attachment edit page, but it's not saving data. And it appears only on edit attachment page (in Media section of WP Admin) but not in media attachment popup. I need it in pop-up and saving data. Any ideas? Help is much appreciated!